# Putting images in a Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I place an image in a Tkinter GUI using the python standard library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't normally use Tkinter, but I'll take a shot at answering. According to Google, loading images in Tkinter has two main gotchas:

1. It only accepts GIFs. ([Example code](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post374412.html#post374412) for using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to convert to GIF while loading)
2. You have to manually keep a reference to images due to an inability to refcount them. ([solution](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)) ([explanation](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/Images))

The example code for loading non-GIF images should also work perfectly well as an example of the basic procedure for displaying images in Tkinter GUIs.

If you'd prefer a more practical example, [PySol](http://www.pysol.org/) is a suite of solitaire games written with Tkinter and [PySolFC](http://pysolfc.sourceforge.net/), its successor, demonstrates the same usage adapted to the new `python-ttk` Tkinter API which Python 2.7 added.

Answer (score 0):

You can Built-In the images on the code encoding it on Base64

Comment: Do tell, this sounds interesting. If I understand correctly the image will be built into the code, right? So it wouldn't depend on any external files.